# Ошибка при создании PostgreSQL триггера: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near $$

Tags: postgresql, моделирование

При попытке создания триггера на online ресурсе моделирования https://www.db-fiddle.com/

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER markk_bi
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON markk
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_datem();
```

Выдаются ошибки:

```
Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NEW.date);"
Schema Error: error: syntax error at or near "RETURN"
Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;"
Schema Error: error: function update_datem() does not exist
```

Как этого избежать?

P.S. Нехорошо сидеть допоздна. Вот и у меня в вопрос вместо `$` пролез `@`. На самом деле вопрос был именно о том, что некоторые DB клиенты, в том числе и тот, который использован на db-fiddle, игнорируют `$$`

### Старый вариант вопроса

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
@BODY@
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
@BODY@
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER markk_bi
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON markk
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_datem();
```

Выдаются ошибки:

```
Schema Error: error: syntax error at or near "@"
Schema Error: error: syntax error at or near "RETURN"
Schema Error: error: function update_datem() does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что эта среда моделирования, да и некоторые клиенты для работы с PostgreSQL базами не понимают, что все заключенное между `$$` и `$$` (или `$BODY$` и `$BODY$`) является, фактически, текстом и должно быть передано серверу единым блоком, без кусков `$$` или `$BODY$`.

Решение, подходящее для db-fiddle как минимум, но скорее всего применимое везде - заменить `$$` или `$BODY$` на `'`, не забыв при этом сдвоить одинарные кавычки везде внутри:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
'
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC(''MONTH'', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER markk_bi
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON markk
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_datem();
```

Вот пример: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/63vo1RyCMorMsZLZjUE6UF/0)

Comment: Интересно, 3000 просмотров этого ответа, и только один голос "за". В то время как на stackoverflow.com этот же ответ (на английском) получил 29 голосов после 24000 просмотров. 
Какие вы, братцы, однако, щедрые! 

Answer (score 0):

В PostgreSQL текст функции (и триггера соответственно тоже) обязан передаваться строкой.

Синтаксиса строковых литералов с символом `@` в PostgreSQL не существует. Поэтому это очевидная синтаксическая ошибка. В PostgreSQL есть синтаксис [`Dollar-quoted String`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_datem()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
 NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NEW.date);
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

И скорей всего вы подразумевали именно его.

Comment: Насчет $ Вы правы, только Ваш вариант в db-fiddle не проходит (`Schema Error: error: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN NEW.dateM = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NEW.date);"`), а мой - проходит.

Comment: Значит вопрос к этому db-fiddle. Для postgresql это корректный запрос.

Comment: Я переформулировал вопрос и переделаю свой ответ, так как идея была именно в том, чтобы дать возможность людям использовать db-fiddle даже несмотря на этот его недостаток

Comment: а, я не обратил внимание что это самоответ